# JavaScript setting Password DIV value doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to use Threema Web without having to enter this stupid password every time. The website is https://web.threema.ch/#!/welcome.

Not entering the password will need you to pair the phone again every time you refresh the page. Entering a password then requires you to enter a password after every refresh/ restart.

I want to automatically enter the password and the login because my PC is safe already.

What I've tried is the following:

```
    //get the wrapping DIV
loginDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('password-entry')[0]  
loginPane = loginDiv.children[0]

    //find the password field
passwordPane = loginPane.children[1]
passwordLabel = passwordPane.children[0]  
passwordDiv = passwordLabel.firstChild
passwordInput = passwordDiv.nextSibling

    //set the password value
passwordInput.value = "0000"

console.log(passwordInput)

    //find and click the "login" button
buttonDiv = passwordPane.children[1]
buttonDiv.click()
```

Running this will make the password placeholder text disappear. However, it will tell you that it's the wrong password. Pre-typing a random text in the password field and then running the Javascript will make the password field show as many censored bubbles as there are characters in the script's password. However, this will still show the "wrong password" error.

I've also tried messing around with virtual keyboard events but that didn't work.

I think there might be some underlying JS setting the password there after every single character but I don't know how to locate/ address this.

An idea on how to get around this would be much appreciated.

The div for the password is made like this

```
<input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.password" ng-disabled="ctrl.formLocked" autofocus="" aria-labelledby="aria-label-password-reconnect" translate-attr="{'placeholder': 'welcome.PASSWORD'}" autocomplete="current-password" class="ng-valid md-input ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-empty" id="input_0" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Password" style="" value="a">
```

however I think that it has to do with an underlaying JS.

Here is the area around the text field

```
<div class="password-entry">
                <label>
                    <p translate="" id="aria-label-password-reconnecte" class="ng-scope"> text </p>
                    <form ng-submit="ctrl.unlockConfirm()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <md-input-container md-no-float="" class="md-block">
                            <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.password" ng-disabled="ctrl.formLocked" autofocus="" aria-labelledby="aria-label-password-reconnect" translate-attr="{'placeholder': 'welcome.PASSWORD'}" autocomplete="current-password" class="ng-pristine ng-valid md-input ng-empty ng-touched" id="input_0" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Passwort" style=""><div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <button class="md-raised md-primary md-button ng-scope md-ink-ripple" type="submit" ng-transclude="" translate="" translate-attr-aria-label="welcome.BTN_RECONNECT" aria-label=" text ">
                            <span translate="" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-scope"> text </span>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    <p>
                        <span translate="" class="ng-scope"> text:</span>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.deleteSession()" translate="" class="ng-scope">text </a>.
                    </p>
                </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: To help you, we need to see the structure of the DOM this code is meant to work with. It has to be **here, on-site**, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Just FWIW, though: Code using fixed indexes and such tends to be brittle. Consider using [`Element#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and similar.

Comment: Hey @T.J.Crowder thanks for your comment, I've added the source of the div to the question. And you are right about the selectors, thanks for the hint

Comment: Thanks for that -- but it's important to post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Hey, I usually do that but like I said I don't know how to convert the Chrome Elements Window to text. I did do it for the password field tho

Comment: Ok now I've found out how

Answer (score 0):

Just target the password field and set the value using the `setAttribute` method:

`document.querySelector('[type="password"]').setAttribute('value', '1234');`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either, I think it's doing pretty much the same as what I've tried

Comment: The `value` **attribute** is not the current value of the `input`. It's the **default** value of the `input`. Setting it won't change the `input`'s value. The value **property** gets and sets the value (`.value = '1234'`). This will also look throughout the document, which may have other `type="password"` fields.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification, I didn't know that but unfortunately this still isn't the solution :/ I don't understand where else it's getting the value from

Answer (score 0):

Since you're targeting a `type="password"` field within the element, you can use [`Element#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector):

```
loginDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('password-entry')[0]  
loginPane = loginDiv.children[0]
// ...
passwordInput = loginPane.querySelector("[type=password]");
passwordInput.value = "0000";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that does the same thing as my code, it blanks out the field when no input was there before or puts the right amount of "censor circles" in the password field when I've typed something manually in there prior to that. 

But either way it doesn't seem to change the value that's being submitted when clicking the button

Comment: @user2330482 - I didn't notice that you're using Angular. You shouldn't be doing direct DOM manipulation like this in Angular. The above definitely works in a normal `form`, but I guess Angular is doing something "special."